# HtmlNode after inserting element code remains same

Tags: c#, html, data-binding, nodes

I have binded TreeNode's with HtmlNode's 
with TreeNode.Tag
And when I change something in treeView I whant dynamically change HtmlDocument (HtmlAgilityPack)

so heres a code that appends an element to both treeview and htmldocument at the same place :

```
      //add element 
        var selected = Hiererchy.SelectedNode;
        if (selected != null && selected.Tag != null)
        {

            HtmlNode htmlSelected = selected.Tag as HtmlNode;
            if (htmlSelected.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                HtmlNode htmlNew = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div></div>");
                htmlSelected.ChildNodes.Add(htmlNew);
                TreeNode newTree = new TreeNode();
                newTree.Tag = htmlNew;
                newTree.Name = htmlNew.Name;
                newTree.Text = formatAsLabel ( "<" + htmlNew.Name + ">" );
                selected.Nodes.Add(newTree);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("can only add node to element");
            }
        }
        refresh();
```

and the new element appears on treeWiev, yet, when I call `document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;` the code stays perfectly the same like before calling the code above. Why is that?

Comment: What does `refresh()` do?

Comment: just takes document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml; and sets it to text field

Comment: You have not add your elmement to your document yet. Like this document.DocumentNode.AppendChild(htmlSelected);

Comment: how can I maintain hierarchy like that? This will insert child to root I think